# Trigger causing primary key violation

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a trigger that we are trying to update so that when a record is updated, the trigger will update a second table. When we activate the change, we get an error

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY contstraint 'KPRIMARY_SO_SalesOrderHeader". Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.SO_SalesOrderHeader". The duplicate key is XXXXXX.

I'm really confused by this because I don't see in the trigger where we are trying to insert a key.

```
ALTER Trigger [dbo].[SO_SALESORDERHEADER_onOrderChange] 
ON [dbo].[SO_SalesOrderHeader] 
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    --+
    INSERT INTO dbo.OrderUpdateQueue (SourceId, OrderNumber, Action)
        SELECT DISTINCT
            N'SO', Inserted.SALESORDERNO, N'U'
        FROM
            Inserted
        LEFT JOIN
            dbo.OrderUpdateQueue ON (Inserted.SALESORDERNO = OrderUpdateQueue.OrderNumber)
                                 AND (OrderUpdateQueue.SourceID = N'SO')
                                 AND (OrderUpdateQueue.Action = N'U')
        WHERE 
            (OrderUpdateQueue.[Key] IS NULL)
            AND (Inserted.SALESORDERNO IS NOT NULL);
    --+ New Trigger Stuff
    UPDATE MO
    SET MO.[ShipDate] = I.ShipExpireDate
    FROM [BACKEND_db].[dbo].[Order] MO
    INNER JOIN Inserted I ON I.SalesOrderNo = MO.OrderId
    WHERE MO.ShipDate <> I.ShipExpireDate;



CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SO_SalesOrderHeader](
[SalesOrderNo] [varchar](7) NOT NULL
  CONSTRAINT [KPRIMARY_SO_SalesOrderHeader] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[SalesOrderNo] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OrderUpdateQueue](
[Key] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[SourceId] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[OrderNumber] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Action] [nchar](1) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_OrderUpdateQueue] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[Key] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

USE [BACKEND_db]
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Order](
[Key] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[OrderId] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
[ShipDate] [datetime] NULL
CONSTRAINT [PK_MasOrder] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[Key] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: What is made up of your primary key? Showing the schema for that table would help us.

Comment: The primary key from the table initiating the trigger is SO_SalesOrderHeader.Salesorderno.  The primary key on the secondary table we are updating is Order.[key]

Comment: What table has a constraint named `'KPRIMARY_SO_SalesOrderHeader`?

Comment: Are there any triggers on the other 2 tables?

Comment: This trigger could be triggering another trigger...are there any other triggers on that table?

Comment: The table SO_SalesorderHeader has the constraint.   No triggers on the other two tables.

Comment: It is probably a problem with the insert or update on `SO_SALESORDERHEADER` before the trigger is even run that is the issue.

Comment: Just to clarify, if I comment out everything after --+ New Trigger Stuff, there is no error/problem with the existing trigger setup.

Comment: Is there another trigger on the MO table ?

Answer (score 0):

How you do not post the schema of OrderUpdateQueue table, I believe the pk is the OrderNumber field. You can try to change your trigger to:

```
ALTER Trigger [dbo].[SO_SALESORDERHEADER_onOrderChange] 
ON [dbo].[SO_SalesOrderHeader] 
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    --+
    INSERT INTO dbo.OrderUpdateQueue (SourceId, OrderNumber, Action)

SELECT DISTINCT
            N'SO', Inserted.SALESORDERNO, N'U'
        FROM
            Inserted 
        WHERE not exists (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.OrderUpdateQueue  where Inserted.SALESORDERNO = OrderUpdateQueue.OrderNumber) 

 UPDATE MO
    SET MO.[ShipDate] = I.ShipExpireDate
    FROM [BACKEND_db].[dbo].[Order] MO
    INNER JOIN Inserted I ON I.SalesOrderNo = MO.OrderId
    WHERE MO.ShipDate <> I.ShipExpireDate;
```

Comment: I'm receiving the same error message with this code.  Forgive my ignorance, by what do you want to see by "posting schema"?  I'll search other posts for an example.

Comment: When we are studying SQL issues related to PK, FK and other violations we need to understand how the tables are the links between them and all problem environment. If you see the comments above, all people are questioning you about tables schema.

Comment: What's the best way to show/describe the schema?  Is there a query I should run & paste results?

Comment: In this case, the best way is generating the script of tables including PK, FKs, and triggers. Is a good practice include some sample data. You can remove the columns that do not participate on the PKs, FKs and the problem.

Comment: Add the scripts to your question.

Comment: Updated Question, is that what you were looking for?

Comment: First, understand the model, second, reproduce the error in my environment  to create a solution

Comment: The OrderUpdateQueue is similar to OrderUpdateQueue? I can not find the schema of this table.

Comment: I copied the wrong table, updated original question.  Sorry!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152280/discussion-between-mauricio-pontalti-neri-and-mattc).